# Like the datagridfield can we create multiple files input dynamically on the form in ploneformgen?

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

Is there a dynamic files upload input just like the datagridfield to upload multiple files dynamically on the input form in ploneformgen?

Answer (score 0):

There is this : http://plone.org/products/collective.upload it may be a start for creating a widget in ploneformgen...